# Multiple cells for a single UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

In my collection view, the cell class must have completely different appearance for different kinds of data in the array.

I am looking for a way to create multiple cells and choose a different one according to the input data, so for example :

```
internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell..  as! kind1
    let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell.. as! kind2
   // here choose a different one for each kind of data
    return cell1
}
```

I am trying to understand if :

1. How to do this and if its the right way in terms of memory ?
2. Is it a good design? how would you go about making a completely different layout of a single cell? ( creating views and hiding them seems like a bad approach)

Comment: It's correct. But I'd recommend to check before hand the data, and then dequeue the correct cell.

Comment: @Larme So is it a good design ? will I have memory issues and overlay of data because of the reusable cells mechanism ? How will this system works with multiple cells? how can it reuse the right ones to the right place ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do something like this

First register multiple cell -

```
[collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCellKind1" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCellKind1"]
[collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCellKind2" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCellKind2"]
```

Now implement cellForItemAt like show -

```
internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if (data.kind == kind1) {
        let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell..  as! kind1

        return cell1
    } else {
        let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell.. as! kind2

        return cell2
    }
}
```

by checking the type of the data you can determine the cell.

Comment: and How would you register them? you register all of them ?

Comment: Well turns out its MUCH more then this. Its really a huge mess. Your answer is too basic.

Comment: Of course it's basic, I thought you know how to register the cells. here's how to register them.
   `[collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCellKind1" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCellKind1"]`
    `[collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCellKind2" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCellKind2"]`

Comment: Completely ignores this problem: "   // here choose a different one for each kind of data".  This gets messy fast.  You have to set the title, description, etc in two different places.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 example, change depending on your needs.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        registerCells()
    }

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .white
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.isPagingEnabled = true
        return cv
    }()

    var cellId = "Cell"
    var celltwoCellId = "CellTwoCell"

    fileprivate func registerCells() {
        collectionView.register(CellOneCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView.register(CellTwoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: celltwoCellId)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.item == 0
        {
            // Cell 1
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CellOne
            return cell
        }
        else
        {
            // Cell 2
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: celltwoCellId, for: indexPath) as! CellTwo
            return cell
        }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to mention this, for any future users who might wonder how to do that. Now, I think it's much easier to just use the `indexPath.item` and check whether or not it's cell 1 or cell 2. Here's an example

```
if indexPath.item == 0 
{
   // Cell 1
   let cell1 = let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as! Cell1
   return cell1
}
else
{
   // Cell 2
   let cell2 = let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! Cell1
   return cell2
}
```

In case you have more than 2 custom `UICollectionViewCells` then just add else if statements and check against its `indexPath.item`.

Comment: then you have an error saying that you have a missing return in a function expected to return uicollectionviewcell