# Different cell appearance for a single collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I was asking here about the option to make a `collectionView` with multiple cells since our cells have a different appearance for different indexs.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273027/multiple-cells-for-a-single-uicollectionview) was not sufficient because other then just create multiple cells and pick one for every index, you have all sorts of problems such as :

1. How can you register multiple classes ? `collectionView.register(FlowViewCell.self`
2. Reusable cells system gets crazy because they are different
3. Every action you do on a cell must be identified with its class and it becomes a mess.

So, I am searching for another way to do so with a **single cell**.

What would be a good way to set **different buttons** in the same position of a cell, and show/enable a different button with different indexes ?

So for `index 1` I have 2 circle buttons, and for `index 2` I have one large wide button? if you just put them on the same spot and hide one you get a strange design.

Comment: 1. is not a problem at all, just register it. 2 if it gets crazy you are probably doing something wrong even for one type of cell

Comment: Is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: yes it is, making changes inside one cell with everything will be a lot more mess

Answer (score 0):

The answer you linked is what you are looking for.
We use 4 different types of cell in our app and we don't have any problem with it.

You don't have to register multiple classes, you can all create them in your storyboard (inside the collectionview), the system will register the classes for you.
And then you call the cells like explain in the answer.

The hard part is having different sizes, we only have two (large cell and square cell, so two square cells fit on the same level), more than that would be tricky, especially different height.
But apart from that you can have different content on each cell without any problem.